# How To Change Multiple Formulas Within A Specific Column Or Multiple Columns

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet in which there are 100 rows and 20 columns. If I want to change the formula from "=SUM" to ="AVERAGE" just for the cells that are present in Column B, without affecting any other columns that might also have "=SUM" formula in them, then how to do that ?

I have tried using Ctrl+F and Replace, but that either replaces just one formula, or replaces the formula from all the Columns. Or I have to manually keep on clicking replace 100 times, to replace the formula within Column B.

Is there any easy way to do this ?
Thanks

Comment: Does selecting the column you want to change not work?

Comment: @Jerry, that does not work. I tried. When you try to REPLACE the formulas, it will either replace one cell at a time, or the complete sheet at one go, but it will not replace within the selected column. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Well, I don't know how or why, but I can't reproduce that behaviour on my Excel. If I select one column and 'Replace All', all the 'sum' formulae in that particular column get replaced with 'average'.

Comment: @Jerry, I find that strange. Please make sure that you have similar formulas which have "Sum Formula" within them in a few other columns as well and then try this method. If you have this formula ONLY inside column B, then obviously it will work well, but the problem comes when you have same formula within other columns, and hitting replace all, replaces the formulas within those other columns as well. Hopefully I have made myself clear. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I did like B and C columns have the formula `=SUM($A$1:$A$100)` and replaced only those in column B. This didn't change the ones in column C at all.

Comment: ok Jerry, I do not know the reason, why it does not works like that on my PC. Anyway the solution provided by Gary has worked well in my case. Thanks for your participation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Columns("B:B").Replace What:="SUM", _
        Replacement:="AVERAGE", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Gary, thank a lot for that. It works perfectly. Although I would still like to know if there is any Direct Way "just like Ctrl+F and replace type of inbuilt method", so that I do not have to use the Macros. Because I will need to perform similar action on multiple columns on a regular basis, so editing the macros for different columns and different formulas will be an issue. Anyway, that was a great help. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: **There is a direct way.**  In fact, I got the macro using the *macro Recorder*  I clicked on the entire column and then <kbd> f </kbd> and then replaced SUM with AVERAGE using the Dialog Box